# THREE.js + .mesh rotation

Tags: model, three.js

I am using THREE.js (.obj Loader) and a model with multiple mesh parts. 
When i made the model i was careful to give each part its own 'geometry to origin' in Blender, but this doesn't export as expected. 
When I try to 'locally' rotate  a sphere ( eg; eyeballs to rotate on their own axis), they will only rotate around the parent(head). I need the sphere meshes to 'spin' within rather than 'orbit' around the head (mesh parent). Any tips or suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the .blender and .obj?

Comment: surely--how/where? i do have dropbox..

Comment: Put it in the Public folder in dropbox and get a public link...

Comment: this is great/thanks!https://www.dropbox.com/sh/23k629ifd826tgp/8Lr7bM31dw

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that, as far as I know, obj do not have hierarchy. So even if you're exporting many objects, all these objects are considered as just one group of subobjects. All of them located in 0,0,0. However, even if they are all at 0,0,0, the vertices of each object is being offsetted so it will look like in Blender only the "center" is not in the same place.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time on this